# what happen if I don't override sizeof when using LruCache class

Tags: java, android

I read some of the sample using LruCache to implement a cache mechanism for storing the bitmap image. But I still don't know how to use it even through I have read the document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html for it.

For example, in document, it mentioned "Returns the size of the entry for key and value in user-defined units." in sizeof(). What is the size of entry mean? is it mean the number of entries it allow, e.g return 10 would allow me to have 10 cache object references.

```
public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
    ImageCache {
public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    return cacheSize;
}

public LruBitmapCache() {
    this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
}

public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
    super(sizeInKiloBytes);
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return getByteCount / 1024;
...
```

In the above code, why it need to divide 1024, what is the propose for it?

Also, the constructor LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes), why the parameter claim it is size in kilobytes? isn't it should be size in bytes according to the document above?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! I am confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LruCache is used to cache a limited number of values.

### But what is this limited number of values?

First option: you want to store `x` elements in the cache, whatever their size in memory.

In this case, you just create a `LruCache` with `x` as the size and you do not override the `sizeOf` method.

For instance:

```
// cache 1000 values, independently of the String size
LruCache<Integer, String> idToCustomerName = new LruCache<>(1000);
```

Second option, you want to store elements so that the sum of the size of all elements do not exceed a given amount.

In this case, you create a `LruCache` with `y` as the overall size and you do override the `sizeOf` that specify the size of one element in the cache.

For instance:

```
// cache an undefined number of ids so that the length of all the strings 
// do not exceed 100000 characters
LruCache<Integer, String> idToCustomerName = new LruCache<>(100000) {
    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(Integer key, String value) {
       return value.length();
    }
};
```

---

To answer your questions about the code, the unit used in the cache does not really matter as long as the `maxSize` variable and the `sizeOf` are the same unit.

In your example, the internal unit of the cache is kilobytes, so that's why you see `/1024` and `/8` in the code, which matches the `getByteCount / 1024;` in the `sizeOf` method.

Comment: thanks. I get your mean that as long as the unit for `maxSize` and `sizeOf` are the same, everything goes correctly. But in your explanation on the second option for the case when i care about the total size of sum of all elements, I have still some confusion. In your code, `sizeOf ` return `value.length()`. Is it main that if I have 4 items in the `LruCache`, their size are different, their are 100,200,300,400. Then, the total is 1000. Given that I set `maxSize` to 100000, e.g `LruCache<>(100000)`. Then, all 4 items are able to store in the cache, right?

Comment: Exactly. Now if you have 50000, then 30000 and then 40000, it is too much (sum is 110000) so the least recently used value(s) will be evicted from the cache to make room for the new one.